# Can we have two Webservices Extension extending from ycommercewebservices in Hybris 6.7

Tags: web-services, sap-commerce-cloud

Can we have 2 extension extended from ycommercewebservices template?
If yes, how to proceed with it ?

We have a requirement in Hybris 6.7 where we need to keep the webservices from two third party integrations separate in two different extensions.

For example webservices integration for third party A in one extension,say A
and webservices integration for third party B in another extension say B.
Now I have extended ycommercewebservices for third party A, it is not giving any build issues.

Now when I extended the webservices for third party B, it is giving build issues.

The issue is, when I extend from ycommercewebservices for third party B, it gives rise to conflicts in items and beans autocreated by extending.
I have tried removing the items and beans which are conflicting but still it is giving build issue.

Did anyone face such a issue?

Is it even feasible to create separate extensions extending from same ycommercewebservices template.

Comment: why two ycommercewebservices extensions? the idea behind ycommercewebservices (aka Omni Commerce Connect aka OCC) is to provide a full blown REST Api for omni channel commerce (for your mobile app, for your decoupled frontend, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't create two extensions using ycommercewebservices, as it's not sensible to have more than one

- If you need to separate the data, use different `BaseSites` with different catalog versions or similar mechanisms
- If you just need to implement a custom REST API, use `ywebservices` as template.

Documentation for `ywebservices` (available since 6.0): https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/eb5f0e9c20464a488466790333e0e6e2.html